# Angular v1.2 animation for images

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, css-animations

I have been going through tutorials and past questions, trying to figure out where my code is going wrong for applying an animation to the transition of the images I am trying to display.

ng-show works effectively to only show the selected picture, but the transition of pictures doesn't pick up the effects I try to apply to it.

```
<!-- Image Buttons -->
<div class="content">
  <div ng-repeat='image in images' class="{{image.cls}}" 
  ng-click="showThis($index)" value="{{image.set}}">
    <label>{{image.title}}</label>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Display Image -->
<div id="imgHolder" ng-view class="slidedown">
    <img ng-repeat="image in images" ng-src="{{image.url}}" 
    alt="{{image.id}}" ng-show="nowShowing==$index">
</div>
```

I realize that I should probably display the images using the same ng-repeat; currently the css to make that happen needs to be adjusted, so that will come later.

Here is .slidedown, containing the animation css:

```
.slidedown {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.slidedown.ng-enter,
.slidedown.ng-leave {
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
  -o-transition: all 1s ease;
  transition: all 1s ease;
}
.slidedown.ng-enter {
  opacity: 0;
}
.slidedown.ng-enter-active {
  opacity: 1;
}
.slidedown.ng-leave {
  opacity: 1;
}
.slidedown.ng-leave-active {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

Can anyone provide any tips, errors, directions to head in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just put the class="slidedown" on the img not the div

```
<div id="imgHolder" ng-view>
    <img ng-repeat="image in images" ng-src="{{image.url}}"  class="slidedown" 
    alt="{{image.id}}" ng-show="nowShowing==$index">
</div>
```

Comment: I gave it a shot, but it didn't produce any changes.  I don't have any errors being shown, so I think that the ng-animate module is being loaded properly as well.

Comment: thank you very much! got it up and running. appreciate your help; now to add something cool via [animate.css](http://daneden.github.io/animate.css/) :)